# Database Does Not Exist?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I found a code tutorial for SQL database sample but I cant seem to make it work

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quiz";
    // tasks table name
    private static final String TABLE_QUEST = "quest";
    // tasks Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_QUES = "question";
    private static final String KEY_ANSWER = "answer"; //correct option
    private static final String KEY_OPTA= "opta"; //option a
    private static final String KEY_OPTB= "optb"; //option b
    private static final String KEY_OPTC= "optc"; //option c
    private SQLiteDatabase dbase;

    public DatabaseHelper(final Context context) {

        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                File.separator + "Quiz" +
                File.separator + TABLE_QUEST,null,1);
    }



    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        dbase=db;
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS" + TABLE_QUEST +"(" +
                KEY_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
                KEY_QUES +"TEXT," +
                KEY_ANSWER + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPTA + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPTB + "TEXT," +
                KEY_OPTC + "TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(sql);
        addQuestions();
```

I also added in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE”/>
```

Logcat

> 11-28 11:06:10.028 13195-13195/com.airgildane.quizapp
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>    ComponentInfo{com.airgildane.quizapp/com.airgildane.quizapp.Quiz1Activity}:
>    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "EXISTSquest": syntax
>    error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE IF NOT
>    EXISTSquest(idINTEGER PRIMARY KEY
>    AUTOINCREMENT,questionTEXT,answerTEXT,optaTEXT,optbTEXT,optcTEXT)

Comment: try adding space after word EXISTS like String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  " + TABLE_QUEST

Comment: : near "EXISTS quest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near
```

[**`SQLiteException`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteException.html)

> A SQLite exception that indicates there was an error with SQL parsing
>   or execution.

Add a space after the `EXISTS` keyword

```
String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUEST +"(" +
             KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
             KEY_QUES +" TEXT," +
             KEY_ANSWER + " TEXT," +
             KEY_OPTA + " TEXT," +
             KEY_OPTB + " TEXT," +
             KEY_OPTC + " TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add a space  after "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ". as it is not able to get the table name from query.